# Changing the Chrome base URL in Brackets?

Tags: javascript, json, adobe-brackets

I'm using Chrome Canary (Nightly). Brackets doesn't recognize it when starting the live server though and throws me an error. How can I change the URL Brackets references Chrome to?

Comment: [howtos](https://trello.com/c/MYaUdJOR/508-live-development-w-custom-chrome-install-e-g-canary-or-portable-chrome), good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no official way to do this yet.

- You can upvote the feature request here: https://trello.com/c/MYaUdJOR/508-live-development-w-custom-chrome-install-e-g-canary-or-portable-chrome
- This experimental patch makes the browser path user-customizable: https://github.com/adobe/brackets/pull/6622. It might land in the next month or two (I'll update this answer if so).
- You can make a [custom build of brackets-shell](https://github.com/adobe/brackets-shell/wiki/Building-Brackets-Shell) with hardcoded changes to launch Canary instead of Chrome. See [this forum post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/brackets-dev/ZE8gUzVIC74/_P4HhBMTWkkJ) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can but what you can do is open the html or whatever file you saved in the desktop or file browser and it works exactly the same!